# jQuery do something until element hits top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, while-loop

I'm blurring out a div on scrolling using the following script. What's the best way to wrap it into something telling it: only do this until #element hits the views top and then stop it. Something like a max-val.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var blurrad = $(document).scrollTop()
    blurrad = blurrad / 100;
    $(".videodummy").css({"-webkit-filter": "blur("+blurrad+"px)","filter": "blur("+blurrad+"px)" })     
});
```

**UPDATE:**
First of all, thanks for your help. I tried to do this:

```
var topdist = $('#indicator').offset().top 

while ( topdist > 0 ) {   
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var blurrad = $(document).scrollTop()
  blurrad = blurrad / 100;
  $(".videodummy").css({"-webkit-filter": "blur("+blurrad+"px)","filter": "blur("+blurrad+"px)" })     
 });

 });
```

So if the div with #indicator hits top it should stop blurring, however this is not working at all.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, you're saying that you're animating it to the top but all you're doing now is blurring the element?

Comment: Ok, again, the code above blurs a div. Endless so to say as long as you scroll. But I want it to stop blurring until a div, let's call it #element hits the top. 

Maybe something like:

     while (#element < top) {
       // do the above code
    }

Comment: I provided an answer based on the vague information you've provided. If it's not quite what you want then let me know.

Comment: The reason it's not working is because you never change the original value from the while.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your try:

```
var topDist = $('#indicator').offset().top;

  $(window).on('scroll', function () {

    topDist = $('#indicator').offset().top;

    if (topDist > 0) {

      var blurrad = $(document).scrollTop();

      blurrad = blurrad / 100;

      $(".videodummy").css({"-webkit-filter": "blur("+blurrad+"px)",
                            "filter": "blur("+blurrad+"px)" });

    }  
  });
```

I'd advice against a while since it's really not needed. Instead check with an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element').offset().top
```

Will give you the distance from top